# Show only login page to guests

Tags: 6

When ever user comes to my website he should be greeted by a pop up or normal login page only. When he logs in whole website should open up to him. SO how do i do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are just so many ways to skin this cat...

Another variant, that does not use panels:

1. Set all content types accessible only to Authenticated users.
2. Enabled "Per content node access control settings" for Page content type. ( Your settings may differe here.)
3. On login page node enable access for Anonymous users.

You could then use Login Destination to redirect users to  home page after logging in.

- See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2724699/604259) that explains how to do this with views.

Another even simpler method requires just a little elbow grease and a bit of thinking but **no** additional module if done right.  Consider the following code, that displays different content depending on if user is logged in:

```
<?php  global $user; ?>
<?php if ($user->uid) : ?>
  Welcome <?php print l($user->name,'user/'.$user->uid); ?>.   <?php print      
l("Logout","logout"); ?>.
<?php else : ?>
  Welcome Guest. <?php print l("Login","user"); ?>/<?php print l("Register","user/register"); ?>.          
<?php endif; ?>
```

So if you have a front-page template, using a conditional like above can give you two totally different outputs depending on the page.

Last but not least, another option I saw mentionned as being noteworthy is using the Role-Theme module, and again theming the authenthicated user with whatever differences you want.

Hope that helps, happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Two separate [Panels everywhere](http://drupal.org/project/panels_everywhere) variants, one with a selection rule "User is anonymous", the other with "User is authenticated", could accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

This is a slight variation on @Letharion's answer, but I just did this for a client.

First, remove all permissions from the Anonymous user.

Then, install [Panels](http://drupal.org/project/panels).

Make a panel page that is only available to the Anonymous user, and put the login form on it.

Set up the global 403 page to point to this page.

Make two panel variants for the home page.  The Authenticated user sees the normal front page.  The Anonymous user just sees the login form and some sort of message (using custom content).

This worked well on the site I just retrofitted.  This is one of the reasons I use Panels from the get-go; it makes changes like this pretty trivial to make.